# Difference between columns in a matrix

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

This was my original table:

```
customers   shopname    custimport
6247        Bison       2014-05-28  
5753        Brownies    2014-05-28  
14315       Falkners    2014-05-28  
6392        Bison       2014-08-31  
5483        Brownies    2014-08-31  
14395       Falkners    2014-08-31
```

In my report, I made this matrix

```
           [custimport]
[shopname] [Sum(customers)]
```

I know that there are only going to be 2 custimport dates, and I need the difference between the sum(customers). Essentially, I need to find how many more customers the shop gained/lost between the 2 import dates. I'm not sure what expression to use to accomplish this.

For reference, this is the matrix right now:

```
       5/28/2014    8/31/2014
Bison       6247    6392
Brownies    5753    5483
Falkners    14315   14395
```

And this is the result I want:

```
       5/28/2014    8/31/2014   diff
Bison       6247    6392        145
Brownies    5753    5483        -270
Falkners    14315   14395       80
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should be your dataset for the matrix.

```
    SELECT ORI.SHOPNAME,
           ORI.CUSTIMPORT,
           B.CUSTOMERS-A.CUSTOMERS AS DIFF
    FROM
      (SELECT SHOPNAME,
              CUSTIMPORT
       FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE) ORI
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT CUSTOMERS,
              SHOPNAME,
              CUSTIMPORT
       FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE)A ON ORI.SHOPNAME=A.SHOPNAME
    AND A.CUSTIMPORT=ORI.CUSTIMPORT
    INNER JOIN
      (SELECT CUSTOMERS,
              SHOPNAME,
              CUSTIMPORT
       FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE)B ON A.SHOPNAME=B.SHOPNAME
    AND A.CUSTIMPORT <> B.CUSTIMPORT
    AND ORI.SHOPNAME=B.SHOPNAME
    ORDER BY A.CUSTIMPORT
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

This expression worked for me:

```
=Sum(Fields!Customers.Value) - Previous(Sum(Fields!Customers.Value))
```

SQL Only:

```
SELECT [shopname], [2014-05-28], [2014-08-31], [2014-05-28] - [2014-08-31] 'Diff'
FROM #Test
PIVOT
(
Sum(customers)
FOR custimport in ([2014-05-28], [2014-08-31])
) AS PVT_Table
```

Comment: Not my downvote but the question is how to do it in Reporting Services. Not SQL. The SQL method relies on hard coding specific column values. A reporting services answer doesn't as this is handled by the matrix.